# React native button within Card affects all other buttons in separate cards due to constant rendering

Tags: react-native, button, binary, expo

I am rendering separate cards in my render function by using data from an array. However I want a button within each Card to be pressed and only affect that exact Card.

```
this.state = {
  isLiked: false,
  feed: [{
    username: ["stuff","here"],
    caption: ["more","stuff"]
  }]
}
toggleLike = () => {
  this.setState({
    isLiked = !this.state.isLiked
  })
}
renderFeed = () => {
    return this.state.feed.map((card, index) => {
      return card.username.map((username, i) => {
        if(card.caption[i])
          return (
            <View>
              <TouchableHighlight 
              onPress={()=>this.toggleModal({caption:card.caption[i],username:card.username[i]})}
              underlayColor="white">
                <Card
                key={`${i}_${index}`}
                containerStyle={{borderRadius:10, marginRight:1, marginLeft:1,}}>
                  <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  </View>
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                      {this.state.isLiked ?(
                        <Avatar rounded icon={{name: 'heart-multiple-outline', type: 'material-community'}} overlayContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#ff4284',marginLeft: 5}} reverse size="small" onPress={()=> this.toggleLike()}/>
    ) : (
     <Avatar
    rounded
    icon={{ name:'heart-multiple-outline', type:'material-community', color: '#ff4284'}}
   overlayContainerStyle={{marginLeft:5}}
   reverse
   size='small'
   onPress={()=> this.toggleLike()}/>
)}
    </View>
  </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'MontserratB', color:'#bf00b9', marginTop:10}} key={username}>{username}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontFamily:'Montserrat', marginTop:10}} key={card.caption}>{card.caption[i]}</Text>
</Card>
</TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
          );
        return <React.Fragment />;
      });
    })
}
render(){
  {this.renderFeed()}
}
```

Is there any way I can make it so that each card's like button is independent?

Here is an expo snack so you can see what I mean. https://snack.expo.io/@sooper_fly/demoforlikes

Comment: Can you explain more for understanding or provide example?

Comment: @Oleg I've edited the post with an expo snack so you can see what I mean. What I want is the individual 'like' button pressed to only change and not the ones that haven't been pressed.

Comment: IsLiked state.  you have to manage for each item

Comment: do you have any suggestions how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build expo snack, Something like this:

https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/demoforlikes

you can improve your code and make card/item component and set the data over props.
Recommend: Work with FlatList

Comment: thank you for the recommendation of looking into FlatList! And your solution is very clever, thank you for teaching me it.